# how can i remove space between constraintlayout and include layers?

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-constraintlayout

I want to remove white space that I show in picture
[Picure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xdnM6.jpg)

I draw red circle around white space on picture
and I want remove it
I search in stackoverflow but in that case i can not find any anwswer.

My main layout is -->
toolbar_normal.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <include layout="@layout/city_detail_act"
        android:id="@+id/content"/>

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tolbar_storyButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#66cc66"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"

        >

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgSetting"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/setting" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgChoiceCity"
                android:layout_width="80dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="181dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="181dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="180dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="180dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/choicecity" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageViewButton"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/home" />
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

My second layout is -->
city_detail_act.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:paddingBottom="65dp"

    >
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tolbar_story"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#66cc66"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
        app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
        app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:gravity="center"

            android:orientation="horizontal"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgTooTitlelbarMainActf"
                android:layout_width="40dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"


                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/adamak" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgTooTitlelbarMainAct"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"

                android:layout_marginStart="180dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="181dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="181dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/title" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgNavigationView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"

                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                android:scaleType="centerInside"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/dot" />


        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tx_state6"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" "
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/adobearabicregular"

                />


            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imv_refresh2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tx_state6"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                android:padding="10px"
                android:src="@drawable/refresh"
                 />

            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/web2"
                android:layout_width="76dp"
                android:layout_height="76dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/imv_refresh2"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                >




            </WebView>


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="13dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="13dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal">


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txMore"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/adobearabicbold"
                    android:text="مشاهده همه..."
                    android:textSize="12sp"

                    />


                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/txYHinCityDetail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/adobearabicbold"
                    android:text="هر آنچه درمورد قم باید بدانید"
                    android:textSize="24sp" />


            </LinearLayout>


            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvListYH"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvListBazar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/progressBar66"
                style="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_above="@+id/rv_listcity"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:indeterminate="true"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

How can i do it work? 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the following line parent tag in file `city_detail_act.xml` should fix it

```
android:paddingBottom="65dp"
```

And add these to your include tag

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```

Also, consider using Bottom Nav layout for UI like this.

Answer (score 0):

First remove this:

```
android:paddingBottom="65dp"
```

Then your include should be like this:

```
<include
    android:id="@+id/content"
    layout="@layout/city_detail_act"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tolbar_storyButton"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```